# How to open secure connection in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, rubygems

I am quite new to ruby here i am opening a secure connection for amazon s3 in ruby.
here i write a simple method as follows when you call this method it establishes a connection but i think it is not as secure

```
def delete_file(path, &block)
    AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection!(:access_key_id => $key, :secret_access_key => $skey)             #here propery connection done  
    AWS::S3::S3Object.delete path, $bkt                                                             #here file gets deleted
    yield true
  end
```

then i searched and i found `start_tls` method of eventmachine from
http://eventmachine.rubyforge.org/EventMachine/Connection.html#start_tls-instance_method

Comment: Use gem https://github.com/marcel/aws-s3

Comment: i already used that but instead of `AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection!(:access_key_id => $key, :secret_access_key => $skey)` i want to use that **start_tls** method

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `:use_ssl => true` as written in the manuals:

> You can specify whether the url should go over SSL with the
>   :use_ssl option:
>
> # Url will use https protocol

```
S3Object.url_for('beluga_baby.jpg', 'marcel',   :use_ssl => true)
```